# What $(prefix) is used for in $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig?

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04, git-config

I know I can set environment variable `prefix` in order to change git configuration directory. But why I should need it? Is same logic available for other programs? Who else uses `prefix` environment variable?

Comment: The use of a prefix to specify an alternate installation location is common and many projects use some mechanism to provide it. Ideally, a project will provide DESTDIR as well for staged installation.

Comment: It's also not an *environment* variable, but rather a build-time configuration.

Comment: you mean I can set `prefix` during build from source? But why some  constant `etc/gitconfig` is left?